# Javascript - Assigning img Ids on Load

Tags: javascript, html, css

I'm having an issue with assigning IDs to elements with the "img" tag, tried finding people with similar problems but I couldn't quite fit them to my own, fairly (entirely) new to Javascript, so I'm probably doing it completely wrong but either way, here's my Javascript:

```js
var imgs = document.getElementsByTag('img');
var count = imgs.length;

window.onload = function() {
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    imgs[i].setAttribute('id', i.toString());
  }
}

function toggleOverlay() {
  var overlay = document.getElementById('overlay');
  var container = document.getElementById('container');
  overlay.style.opacity = .8;
  if (overlay.style.display == "block") {
    overlay.style.display = "none";
    container.style.display = "none";
  } else {
    overlay.style.display = "block";
    container.style.display = "block";
  }
}

function draw(ID) {
  var canvasContainer = document.getElementById("container")
  var c = document.createElement('canvas');
  c.width = 500;
  c.height = 110;
  c.id = "product";
  var img = document.getElementById(ID);
  var ctx = c.getContext("2d");
  ctx.rect(0, 0, c.width, c.height);
  ctx.drawImage(img, 0, 0);
  canvasContainer.appendChild(c);
}
```

```css
div#overlay {
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
  background: #000;
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  text-align: center;
}
div#container {
  display: none;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
  margin: 150px auto 0px auto;
  width: 600px;
  height: 360px;
  background: #FFF;
  color: #000;
  border-style: solid;
  border-color: #f00;
  border-radius: 5px;
  border-width: 4px;
  box-shadow: 5px 6px RGBa(0, 0, 0, 0.4);
}
div#wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  padding-left: 24px;
}
#product {
  position: relative;
  width: 85%;
  height: auto;
  z-index: 4;
  margin-top: 10px;
  margin-left: 10px;
}
.clickable::after {
  width: 25%;
  height: auto;
}
#addtocart {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  margin-right: 5px;
  background-color: #f00;
  color: #FFF;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  width: 6em;
  height: 3em;
}
#addtocart:hover {
  transition-duration: 0.2s;
  background-color: #e00;
  opacity: 0.8;
}
.clickable {
  cursor: pointer;
}
div#view {
  position: absolute;
  text-align: center;
  background: #f00;
  color: #FFF;
  border-radius: 2px;
  width: 6em;
  height: 2em;
}
div#view:hover {
  display: block;
  z-index: 2;
}
div#images:hover {
  background-color: RGBa(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}
#link {
  background-color: #f00;
  border: none;
  border-radius: 3px;
  display: none;
  color: #FFF;
}
```

```html
<div id="overlay"></div>
<div id="container">
  <p id="information"></p>
  <button id="addtocart">Add to Cart</button>
</div>
<div id="wrapper">
  <h2>Test</h2>

  <p id="name"></p>
  <div id="images">
    <img class="clickable" onmousedown="toggleOverlay(); draw(this.id);" src="PIXEL-TITANIUM-SHAFT-GOLD-MEDIUM-133000.gif" /img>
    <img class="clickable" onmousedown="toggleOverlay(); draw(this.id);" src="MichaelVanGerwen.gif" /img>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

The function you want is `document.getElementsByTagName` and you should move it inside the `window.onload` function, just to be sure that you fetch all the `img` elements only after they are created.

```
window.onload = function() {
imgs=document.getElementsByTagName("img");
count=imgs.length;
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    imgs[i].setAttribute('id', i.toString());// or simply imgs[i].id=i;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Replace your first line with `document.getElementsByTagName('img');`

Comment: Thanks, I knew it'd be something really simple. :)

Comment: No problem. By the way, you should get into the habit of using a JavaScript console. They'll point errors like this out to you. Most can be accessed by pressing f12 in a browser. :)

Comment: Thanks for the advice, I have firebug for Firefox but never really thought to use it haha :)

Answer (score 0):

You need to define the imgs array after window load. Since images need to be loaded first before you traverse the dom to fetch them. I understand if you are defining your scripts before the body end tag then too.

And corrected the typo `getElementsByTagName`

```
var imgs;
var count;

window.onload = function() {
  imgs = document.getElementsByTagName('img');
  count = imgs.length;
  for (i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    imgs[i].setAttribute('id', i.toString());
  }
}
```